# Kusto Query Dynamic sort Order

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have started working on Azure Data Explorer( **Kusto**) recently.

My requirement to make sorting order of Kusto table in dynamic way.

---

// Variable declaration

```
        let SortColumn ="run_date";
        let OrderBy="desc";
```

// Actual Code

**tblOleMeasurments
| take 10
|distinct  column1,column2,column3,run_date
|order by SortColumn OrderBy**

Here My code working fine till Sortcolumn but when I tried to add [OrderBy] after [SortColumn] kusto gives me error .

My requirement here is to pass Asc/desc value from Variable [OrderBy].

Kindly assist here with workarounds and solutions which help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort column and order cannot be an expression, it must be a literal ("asc" or "desc"). If you want to pass the sort column and sort order as a variable, create a union instead where the filter on the variables results with the desired outcome. Here is an example:

```
let OrderBy = "desc";
let sortColumn = "run_date";
let Query = tblOleMeasurments | take 10 |distinct column1,column2,column3,run_date;
union 
(Query | where OrderBy == "desc" and sortColumn == "run_date" | order by run_date desc), 
(Query | where OrderBy == "asc" and sortColumn == "run_date" | order by run_date asc)
```

The number of union legs would be the product of the number of candidate sort columns times two (the two sort order options).

Comment: Thanks a lot , Looks fine for me .

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be sorting by a calculated column, which is based on your `sort_order` and `sort_column`. The example below works for numeric columns

```
let T = range x from 1 to 5 step 1 | extend y = -10 * x;
let sort_order = "asc";
let sort_column = "y";
T
| order by column_ifexists(sort_column, "") * case(sort_order == "asc", -1, 1)
```

Comment: In case it's of interest to anyone - the `union` solution and the calculated column solution both seem to perform similar on a 500k row test set with only difference that the calculated column solution uses approx 40% more memory.